# cookies only shown in application tab after beeing sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

Currently running a nodejs server on localhost with a selfsigned cert to be able to use https, when logging is done the back end responds like this

```
var token = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: user.id,
      },
      process.env.API_SECRET,
      {
        expiresIn: "10 days",
      }
    );

    //responding to client request with user profile success message and  access token
    res.cookie("jwt", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "None",
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      domain: "localhost",
    }); //send token as a cookie when logging in
    res.status(200).send({
      message: "Login successfull",
    });
```

the cookie is visable in the application tab on chrome dev tools but when i refresh this page the cookie dissapears. Url for login = "http://127.0.0.1:5500/src/html/login.html"

now comes the mystery, the cookie is not visalbe but whenever i make any type of request to the backend server the cookie show upp, for example i make a GET request from another page "http://127.0.0.1:5500/src/html/work-list.html" the cookie shows up. this get request dose not have "credentials:include"

i tried to change the domain several times and i have also tried to include a path:"/" in the res.cookie parameters, the cookie still behaves the same, its like the cookie dosent exist untill i make any type of request, what i did notice was that i can still use the cookie to validate my token since i do have a function for POST data that requiers a valid JWT, even tho i can not see it in the applications tab i can still use it to send said POST request

```
fetch("https://localhost:8000/wiki", {
    credentials: "include",
    method: "POST",
    body: CreateFormData(),
  })
```

```
app.post("/wiki", verifyToken, upload.array("files"), CheckFiles); //creates req.files array
```

im not sure if this is how its supposed to work but when googeling this issue the past 2 days i cant seem to find much. i will include github links to both frontend and backend here

the cookies are not visable in the url bar at all

the cookies are set from a fetch POST request to https://localhost:8000/login

Front-end:https://github.com/EliasJovancicPersson/GymnasieArbete
Back-end:https://github.com/EliasJovancicPersson/gymnasie-arbete-backend

Comment: You say you are running an HTTPS server, but the login URL starts with `http://`.

Comment: An insecure origin (e.g. `http://localhost`) cannot set a `Secure` cookie. Also, browsers reject attempts to set a cookie with `Domain=localhost` from Web origin `http://127.0.0.1:5500`, because `localhost` doesn't domain-match `127.0.0.1`. See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis/#name-domain-matching

Comment: @HeikoTheißen thats only for the forntend portion of the website, the back end is a separate domain wich runs the https.

Comment: Then when you reload the page over HTTP, the cookie is not accessible because the page is insecure. But it is accessible to a request you make over HTTPS. At what point in time it shows up on the Application tab sounds like a browser implementation detail.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen the cookies show up in the applications when i get the response from the login backend function, but they also show up when i get any kind of response from the backend even when i just do a GET request with no credentials included. its like they are hidden until i send a fetch request

Comment: I assume they become visible after the first HTTPS request.

Comment: yes that sounds correct actually, may it be that a HTTPS request is needed for them to be shown? @HeikoTheißen

Comment: Yes, because secure cookies can only be sent over HTTPS.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen okay, i now have both domains running HTTPS with a self signed cert, however it still behaves in the same way. The cookie JWT is only visible whenever I send a Fetch request. I dont understand how I am supposed to work around this issue so that my JWT cookie is visible on all pages. It gets sent from all pages as a cookie to the backend its just not visible to me in the application view. I want the cookie to be stored between changing pages, is this not possible without localstorage?